# MS ACCESS - Hierarchical tree sort

Tags: ms-access, sorting, treeview, tree, parent-child

I'm struggling with a sorting problem.

I've got a table which is as follows:

```
aspect_id (int)
aspect_text (memo)
root_id (int) which has as a foreign key a aspect_id
```

I've got a non cyclic tree with the following dummy data:

```
aspect_id  aspect_text  root_id 

1          root         null
2          aspect1      1
3          aspect2      1
4          aspect3      2
5          aspect5      4
```

In the example the data is sorted correctly, in my database its not. I want to sort that it starts at the root element, then finds a child, output that child and does that recursively.

With CTE it is fairly doable. Access doesn't support this. With CTE it would be something like:

```
WITH aspectTree (aspect_id, root_id, Level#) AS 
(
        Select 
            aspect.aspect_id, 
            aspect.root_id,
            0
        FROM aspect
        WHERE aspect.aspect_id = 44
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            aspect.aspect_id, 
            aspect.root_id, 
            T.Level# + 1
        FROM aspect
        INNER JOIN aspectTree AS T 
            On T.aspect_id = aspect.root_id
)
SELECT * FROM aspectTree;
```

Comment: What dooes the acronym CTE mean?

Comment: CTE = Common Table Expression, part of the SQL-99 Standard and introduced into SQL Server 2005. See MSDN 'Using Common Table Expressions' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx).

Comment: Which version of Access are you using ? Access 2010 has a new field type to handle hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a consideration, this fairly simple solution would work:

```
Public Function GetLevel(ByVal lngNodeId As Long) As Long

    Dim varRootId As Variant

    varRootId = DLookup("root_id", "aspect", "aspect_id=" & lngNodeId)

    If IsNull(varRootId) Then
        GetLevel = 0
    Else
        GetLevel = GetLevel(varRootId) + 1
    End If

End Function
```

You could then use that function in your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT aspect.*
FROM aspect
ORDER BY GetLevel([aspect_id]), aspect_text
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following will work for you but here you go using Bill of Materials algorithms.

- [Bill Of Materials](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0027.htm)
- [BOM, with Joe Celko Nested Sets](http://www.mvps.org/access/queries/qry0023.htm)

Comment: The 'Joe Celko' one will not work because the OP here is using the adjacency list model not the nested sets model... unless they completely revise their schema, drastic but may be worth consideration ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its full of test code, but i did something that works in vb code. Its really ugly and slow, but it works. Im now cleaning it up, just got it working. The solution is a recursive function. The function calls on itself if it finds that the node has childs. It seemed to overwrite the arrays, that why its an array of arrays. The code is hideous, but it works and thats all i needed. The database is and will stay small (<1000 records) so speed is not an issue. Thanks for the comments and answers, if someones knows i better solution, i would love to hear it.

```
Private Function Fillarray(value As Integer)
Dim done As Boolean

j = j + 1
esql = "select aspect_id from aspect where root_id = " & value
Set rec(j) = db.OpenRecordset(esql)
Dim k As Integer
k = j
Do While Not rec(k).EOF
done = True
arra(i) = rec(k).Fields(0) 
Dim temp1 As String
temp1 = DLookup("[aspects]", "[aspect]", "[aspect_id] = " & rec(k).Fields(0))
db.Execute "INSERT INTO sortedaspect (aspect_id, aspect) VALUES (" & rec(k).Fields(0) & ", '" & temp1 & "')"

        esql = "select aspect_id from aspect where root_id = " & rec(k).Fields(0)

        Set rec(90) = db.OpenRecordset(esql)
        Do While Not rec(90).EOF And done
            'fix this without a loop,you only need to know if it has childs...
            Fillarray (rec(k).Fields(0))
            done = False

        Loop
      'next child

rec(k).MoveNext
'value = arra(i)
i = i + 1
'MsgBox arra(i - 1)
Loop

End Function
```